# Redirect to previous page in Codeigniter after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-url

In one of my CI application there is an user login section. The users are restricted to some pages , ie only members can view that page. So there are two controllers users ( which contain register , login .. ) , admin ( secure pages ) .

My question is if user visit a page on admin then if that user is not logined then have to show login page ( in users controller ) and after successful login it will redirect to the previous page in which user tried to access.

for eg : If user click "myaccount" page then if user is not logined it will redirect to "login" page after successful login will return back in "myaccount" page

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first create page >>name login.php in the view folder

and write your login page

in the controller you can try this code

```
public function mypage()
    {
    $this->user_model->check_user_login();

    $this->load->view('cp/tamplate_header');
    }
```

and write rhis code in the User_model

```
function check_user_login()
{
    if(! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        redirect('login');
    }

    if($this->session->userdata('user_active') == false)
    {
        redirect('pagename');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and after successful login how can we redirect to previous page automatically ?

Comment: after login set session 'logged_in' = true and call this function check_user_login() in all pages

Comment: To automatically redirect to previous page after login, one technique is to include that page's url in the link to the login. That way the link remains even after mutliple attempts to login. Of course you should validate that link before redirecting! Hope it helps!

Comment: try this

http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html
or download this code
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-6-login/